# How to initialize data before rendering in React.js

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm sorry for being a beginner in React.
I try to draw charts using the rechart library.

At first, I fetch data from the server using API and pass this to the subcomponent as props.
If I use `this.props.selectablefields` in render() directly then it works well. But I have to implement some functions when clicking the legend label.

So I set state by this data and use that state in render().
But this state is empty at the first time(first loading).
If I resave my code without any fix then this is works. (not refresh..)
This is my code.

```
export default class AnalysLineChart extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.selectBar = this.selectBar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      labels: this.props.selectablefields
    }
  }

  selectBar(event) {
    //do something......
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LineChart width={300} height={250} data={this.props.data}>
        <XAxis dataKey="date"/>
        <YAxis/>
        <Legend onClick={this.selectBar} />
        {
          //this code is work well but can't implement legend click functions
          //this.props.selectablefields.map((label, index)) => (   
          this.state.labels.map((label, index) => (
            <Line key={index} type="monotone" dataKey={label.key}  stroke={label.color} />
          ))
        }
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

note:
When I click the legend label then It will show and hide the chart according to the clicked legend.

selectBar function is like this.(but this is not important in this problem)

```
selectBar(event) {
    let updatedLabels = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.labels.length; i++) {
      let label = this.state.labels[i];
      
      if (label.key != event.dataKey) {
        updatedLabels.push(label);
      } else {
        if (/\s/.test(label.key)) {
          let newLabel = { key: label.key.trim(), color: label.color };
          updatedLabels.push(newLabel);
        }
        else {
          let newLabel = { key: label.key + " ", color: label.color };
          updatedLabels.push(newLabel);
        }
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      labels: updatedLabels
    });
  }
```

The chart looks like this.

[image]

This is a picture when hiding the CPA graph after clicking the CPA legend.

[image]

Comment: yes. you are right. But this was not my problem of this question. This is working even like that. Thank you anyway for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solve this problem.
Maybe  this is because `setState` function operates asynchronously.
I fixed my code like this and working well.

```
export default class AnalysLineChart extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.selectBar = this.selectBar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      labels: []
    }
  }

  selectBar(event) {
    //do something......
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({
          labels: this.props.selectablefields
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LineChart width={300} height={250} data={this.props.data}>
        <XAxis dataKey="date"/>
        <YAxis/>
        <Legend onClick={this.selectBar} />
        {  
          this.state.labels.map((label, index) => (
            <Line key={index} type="monotone" dataKey={label.key}  stroke={label.color} />
          ))
        }
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are describing your issue clearly enough. 
Normally what you'd do is what you did which is mapping `this.props.selectablefields` because saving that prop into state seems like an overkill.....
What is it exactly that you want to achieve when the Legend component is clicked on?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I updated my question. There are a few graphs in one chart. If I click special legend then that graph will hide and If I click again then that graph will show.